# Send extra_data to simplecart.js with sendform to email address

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation, simplecart

I am to trying to send additional details with the sendform method in simplecart. I am able to send the item details, but I am unable to send the extra_data attibute.

Script at the bottom of the checkout page

```
<script>
simpleCart({
checkout: {
type: "SendForm" ,
url: "http://www.####.com/process/sendform.php"
 },

 extra_data: {
      company: "Company A", 
      email: "email@companya.com"

   },

    });
</script>
```

Php Script

```
<?php
 $to = '####@gmail.com';
 $subject = 'Simple Cart Order';
 $content = $_POST;
 $body = '';
 for($i=1; $i < $content['itemCount'] + 1; $i++) {
 $name = 'item_name_'.$i;
 $quantity =  'item_quantity_'.$i;
 $price = 'item_price_'.$i;
 $company = 'extra_data_company_'.$i;
 $body .= 'item #'.$i.': ';
 $body .= $content[$name].' '.$content[$quantity].' '.$content[$price]  $content[$company];
 $body .= '<br>';
}
 $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
 'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
  Header('Location: thankyou.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just can use 
$_POST['company'];

and use 
print_r($_POST); to see all parameters, which send simple cart

Answer (score 0):

I think you just had your bracket in the wrong place. Like this:

```
<script>simpleCart({
    checkout: {
        type: "SendForm" ,
        url: "http://www.####.com/process/sendform.php",
        extra_data: {
            company: "Company A", 
            email: "email@companya.com"
        }
    }
    });
</script>
```